# Declare function inside scope and call it later

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Calling the callService function fails. Instead none of my console messages are showing in the console except for 'making a controller....'.  I'm using the directive ng-click="callService()" to make the call from an HTML button. I'm new to angular, can someone point me in the right direction? Code is below.

```
(function() {
    console.log('making a controller....');
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myModule').controller('myController', myController);

    myController.$inject = ['$scope','$http'];


    function myController($scope, $http) {
        console.log("controller initialized...");

            $scope.callService = function(){
            console.log("callService called...");
            var urlSearchService = 'http://domain/proj/rs/stuff/moreStuff';
            var skuVal = $scope.skuField;
            var mVenVal = $scope.mVendorField;
            //need to somehow specifiy that xml is a @FormParam
            var xmlItemSearchRequest = "<ItemSearchRequest>"
                            +"<skuid>" + skuVal + "</skuid>"
                            +"<mvendor>" + mVenVal + "</mvendor>"
                        +"</ItemSearchRequest>";

            console.log('calling: ' + urlSearchService + 'sending xml: ' + xmlItemSearchRequest);
            $http.post(urlSearchService, xmlItemSearchRequest).
                success(function(data){
                    $scope.searchResults = data;
                    console.log('call to ' + urlSearchService + ", was a success.");
                }).error(function(data, status) {
                      console.error('Calling error', status, data);
                });
        };

    };
})();
```

Comment: `$scope.callService = function()..` You may want to check the startup documentation for angular.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the `callService` function inside the scope of the controller function, so it won't be accessible from the `$scope`. You need to add it to the `$scope` in order to be able to use it in your templates.

Instead of:

```
var callService = function(){
```

Do:

```
$scope.callService = function(){
```

As per your latest comment, you are not binding correctly the controller.

This:

```
<div data-ng-controller="inventorySearchController"><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="callService()" value="Search" /></div> –
```

Should be:

```
<div data-ng-controller="myController"><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="callService()" value="Search" /></div> –
```

Comment: I have tried that also, and updated my code here to reflect that change.  Sadly, still no luck.

Comment: @Accribus share the html template where you are using this app and controller and the ng-click directive. maybe there's something wrong there

Comment: <div data-ng-controller="inventorySearchController"><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="callService()" value="Search" /></div>

Comment: @Accribus you are not using the controller you've provided. Check my edit.

Comment: Sorry.... my comment had a typo.  

<div data-ng-controller="myController"><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="callService()" value="Search" /></div>

Comment: and where is your ng-app directive?

Comment: Not shown, but in the source code. The first console line does appear as per OP. The others do not, suggesting that calling callService() fails.

Comment: Incorrect. The first console line will always appear. If the callService call was failing, you would see the second console.log("controller initialized..."). As per your question you are not seeing that log, meaning that the controller has never been initialized.

Comment: Yes, that's where I'm stuck. Only the first console works.  How do I fix it?

Comment: providing more code. the module declaration and where the  ng-app directive is called might help a lot.